# Strange (for me) declaration of function

Tags: c

What that declaration means in C ?

```
void help_me (char *, char *);
```

I'm newbie, but I know about pointers. Seems like this is something different ?

Comment: It's a declaration of a function taking two pointers to `char`. If you understand about pointers, I think you just need to learn about functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This declaration says that `help_me` is a function taking two pointers to `char` (for example, two strings).

For a function prototype declaration the variable names are optional: `void help_me (char *, char *);` and `void help_me (char * foo, char * bar);` are equivalent.

Comment: And the void means that it returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the difference between 
help_me (char *, char *); and
help_me (char *x, char *y);
?

Comment: @jingo I updated my answer, also see the other answers to your question.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) for a function. It doesn't give the argument names because it isn't strictly require in a prototype.

Here it is declaring that there exists a function, `help_me` that takes 2 arguments both of type `char *` and returns nothing.

Comment: Not only is it unnecessary to include argument names in a prototype; it's also harmful. It will break when the names conflict with the name of a preprocessor macro. System headers can avoid this by using the reserved namespace (e.g. double-underscore prefix), but user headers would have to document their own reserved namespace. Personally I think it makes much more sense just to omit argument names and use a comment if you want to document the purpose of the arguments in the header...

Comment: True. However giving names to arguments makes documenting them easier and in the absence of documentation gives a clue to the intent of each argument.

Comment: What I was saying is that putting a comment on the line immediately before the prototype is just as useful as documentation, and avoids the namespace pollution issue.

Comment: In the comment how do you refer to each argument? Referring to them by their position seems error prone and rather unfriendly. While documentation that makes use of named arguments is dime a dozen, I have yet encounter any where this is not the case. Perhaps you can link to an example I can further my education?

Comment: Something like `/* strcpy(dest, src) */ char *strcpy(char *restrict, const char *restrict);`

Comment: Ah, thank you - I give this a go in my next project :) The lesson is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a prototype, and in a prototype only the type of arguments are needed, i..e you don't need to state something like:

```
void help_me (char* a_char, char* another_char);
```